# Find the angle between planes given three lines

Tags: vectors

Four non-coplanar points form the below arrangement, such that the angle AOB=γ and so on as labelled.

[image: An image showing the assignment of points and angles]

The question is, how can one find the angle between plane$AOB$ and $AOC$ then $AOB$ and $COB$ etc.?

Comment: Use [spherical law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines), the angle $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ here is equivalent to the side lengths of a spherical triangle. The angle between the plane corresponds to the interior angles of the spherical triangle.

Comment: I am aware of this, in fact, this is where my question began, I am trying to find the surface angles on a spherical triangle, but the central angles are all that I have.

Comment: I hope you don’t mind, @achillehui, that I have expanded your comment to an answer.

Comment: @Lubin thanks for writing that up as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\vec {OA}= \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ - arbitarily pointing it along the $x$-axis.

Let $\vec {OB}= \begin{bmatrix}\cos \gamma \\ \sin \gamma \\0\end{bmatrix}$ - unit vector in the $x$-$y$ plane at an angle $\gamma$ to the $x$-axis.

Let $\vec {OC}= \begin{bmatrix}p\\ q \\1\end{bmatrix}$

Create one equation from the fact that $\vec {OC}$ and $\vec {OB}$ are at an angle $\alpha$ to each other:

$\frac {\vec {OB} . \vec {OC}}{OC} = \cos \alpha$

Similarly

$\frac {\vec {OA} . \vec {OC}}{OC} = \cos \beta$

These give two simultaneous equations for $p$ and $q$. Solve and proceed to the next step:

Use the vector product of $\vec {OA}$ and $\vec {OB}$ to find the normal $\vec {n_1} = \vec {OA} \times \vec {OB}$ to the plane $AOB$.

Use the vector product of $\vec {OA}$ and $\vec {OC}$ to find the normal $\vec {n_2} = \vec {OA} \times \vec {OC}$ to the plane $AOC$.

The angle between the planes is equal to the angle between the normals, so use the scalar product $\vec {n_1} . \vec {n_2}$ to find this angle.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately, the coordinates of A,B and C are not known. Setting up a reference frame would probably involve Euler's angles, which I have not learned in any systematic way.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll add in something at the start of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

As Achille Hui suggested, when you put your eye at $O$ and look to the surface of the sphere, you see that the angles are the measures of three great-circle arcs. In other words, you’re looking at a spherical triangle with sides $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$. There’s the Law of Cosines that applies here, it gives the cosine of the angle opposite $\alpha$, namely the angle between the plane $COA$ and the plane $BOA$, I’ll call this angle $\Bbb A$, as follows:
$$
\cos\alpha=\cos\beta\cos\gamma+\sin\beta\sin\gamma\cos\Bbb A
$$
The sign between the two terms is correctly $+$, not $-$, in case you’re worried.

Comment: That is very helpful answer.

Comment: Yes, it’s relatively quick, certainly easily programmed, and has the advantage (over anything using the spherical Law of Sines) that since your angles will always be between $0$ and $180^\circ$, the $\arccos$ function is one-to-one and will give a reliable answer.